# Winforms DataGridView Cell Selection Change gives error

Tags: winforms, datagridview, selection

I have a winforms screen and the below code in Form_Activated event.

```
if (genlGrid1.Rows.Count > 0 && genlGrid1.Rows.Count <= genlGridIndex + 1 && (genlGridIndex >= 0 && genlGridIndex < 2))    
{    
    //Looks like below line is where exception occurs    
    genlGrid1.Rows[genlGridIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;     
}
```

I'm very sure that the grid has 2 rows and 9 cells when this line of code is executed.

When this line of code is executed, I get the error below. No idea what is going on with the grid. What is SetCurrentCellAddressCore and why are we getting this exception??

Can some one please help?

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   columnIndex    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32
>   columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean
>   setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean
>   validateCurrentCell, Boolean
>   throughMouseClick)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetSelectedCellCoreInternal(Int32
>   columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean
>   selected)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.set_Selected(Boolean
>   value)

Comment: What is the value of genlGridIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
if (genlGrid1.Rows.Count > 0 && 
    genlGrid1.Rows.Count >= genlGridIndex + 1 && 
   (genlGridIndex >= 0 && genlGridIndex < 2))    
{        
    genlGrid1.Rows[genlGridIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;     
}
```

?

Note `genlGrid1.Rows.Count >= genlGridIndex + 1`

Comment: I dont think this is cause of the issue. As we check for genlGridIndex to be either 0 or 1, it will not execute the code in the if condition when genlGridIndex is 0. so it would execute for when genlGridIndex is 1. When its 0, it would not throw exception, instead it would not execute the code. There is some other thing which is cause of the excepti